# Rails Engine RouteProxy outside View and Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-engines

I am trying to eval a routing helper string in a class that is designed for unsafe code evaluation. Basically I have a class SafeEval which will evaluate string in a sandboxed class. I did following to get route helpers working in SafeEval

```
include ActionController::UrlFor
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

All ruote helpers are working except engine route proxies. In my views and controllers I can call blog.page_path(@page) but I can't call blog.page_path in SafeEval - I get blog not defined. I checked in my view and blog is RouteProxy.

So my question is how can I get engine route proxy in a class outside view/controller

(SafeEvla does not do a lot of sandboxing. you can assume very simple structure: a method that just runs eval(str) for now inside a SafeEval class.)

Answer (score 4):

I think including the mounted helpers in your class would solve the problem:

```
include Rails.application.routes.mounted_helpers
```

Comment: Amazing! After consulting 20 other SOF/blog posts/Medium articles on how to include mounted Engine routes into a Helper module of the "main app", I have finally found this undocumented approach that works. You deserve a medal and a gold star, @banhill!